# CSS terminology: what's this called in a property value?

Tags: css

In a css property, there are certain value declarations that look like functions, eg

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

or

```
background-image: url('bg.png');
```

The first part is called the property, eg `background` and `background-image`. The second part in general is called the value. But what is the part outside of the parentheses called, eg `rgba(...)` and `url(...)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generically, they're just called "<whatever> notations"; see [this part of the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#image-notation) for example:

> The `image()` function allows an author to:
>
> - use media fragments to clip out a portion of an image
> - specify fallback images in case the preferred image can't be decoded or is a type that > the browser doesn't recognize
> - use a solid color as an image
> - annotate an image with a directionality
>
> The `image()` notation is defined as:
>
> ```
> <image-list> = image( [ <image-decl> , ]* [ <image-decl> | <color> ] )
> <image-decl> = [ <url> | <string> | <element-reference> ]
> ```
>
> Each `<string>` or `<url>` inside `image()` represents an image, just as if the `url()` notation had been used. As usual for URLs in CSS, relative URLs are resolved to an absolute URL (as described in Values & Units [CSS3VAL]) when a specified `image()` value is computed.

So `url('bg.png')` is the `url()` notation. However, you can get more specific. Values that represent images, such as:

- `linear-gradient(red, white)`
- `url('../images/hello.png')`
- `radial-gradient(orange, yellow)`
- `cross-fade(image1, image2)`

Are called *image values*. This applies to things like `rect()`, too, which is a [*shape value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/shape)<sup>1</sup>. As for `calc()`, that's just generally called an expression, I believe.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Note that in the sidebar, `rect()` is also referred to as a function.</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the fast and well-cited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not called anything in particular. It's all just part of the value.